# How to pass props to layout.js from page.js in the app directory of Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to pass `props` to `layout.js` of Next.js 13. Here's what it'd look like:

```js
// layout.js
export default Layout({children}) {
  return (
    <>
      {/* I want to render different `text` depending on the page.js I'm rendering */}
      <h1>{text}</h1>
      {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

Unfortunately, I end up doing this:

```js
// CustomLayout.js
export default Layout({children, text}) {
  return (
    <>
      {/* I want to have different `text` depending on the Page.js I'm rendering */}
      <h1>{text}</h1>
      {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

My question is, is it possible to pass props to layouts in Next.js 13? Is there a better approach?

```js
// In every page.js
import Layout from "somewhere/CustomLayout";

export default Page() {
  return (
    <Layout text="My text">
    {/* My Page Content */}
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Comment: what you are doing is fine, I don't see what is your problem

Comment: I just thought it loses the magic of the new router system of next 13

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be trying to pass custom `props` to [`Layout`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts), inside Next.js's new `app` directory, as this component is created by you, but Next.js itself would call it, by giving it two `props`:

> ### children (required)
>
> Layout components should accept and use a `children` prop. During rendering, children will be populated with the route segments the layout is wrapping. These will primarily be the component of a child Layout (if it exists) or Page, but could also be other special files like Loading or Error when applicable.

> ### params (optional)
>
> The dynamic route parameters object from the root segment down to that layout.

Wanting to pass custom `props` to it, I think, is because you wanna use it in different places, but the whole idea is to have one `Layout` by route segment. And subroutes inherit the layout of outer ones. For example, `layout.js` inside `app/blog` gets wrapped by `layout.js` inside `app/`.

Having `Layout` called inside `page.js` as you did, is like having any wrapper, but not a [`Layout`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/pages-and-layouts#layouts) as designed by Next.js with its specific abilities:

> A layout is UI that is shared between multiple pages. On navigation, layouts preserve state, remain interactive, and do not re-render. Layouts can also be nested.

```
import Layout from "somewhere/CustomLayout";

export default Page() {
  return (
    // ⚠️ this would behave like a normal wrapper, but not as a Layout as Next.js defines it
    <Layout text="My text"> 
    {/* My Page Content */}
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

A `Layout` is not a global state provider. For this need consider using already known technics, for example, a [`context`](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#context).

Answer (score 0):

No, you shouldn't pass in additional props to a layout.js file in nextjs 13 appdir.

As @YoussoufOumar pointed out, you shouldn't be calling Layout yourself. It sits at the root (at least for all the components under it), so should be treated as such.

Your approach of creating a custom layout that passes text as a prop is a reasonable approach.